# Call server side functions from the client in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post, get

I started learning web development and want to change data on the server when calling functions on the client.

So this is my example server

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'index'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Public')));

app.get('/profile', function (req, res) { // Render the HTML
  res.render('profile');
});

app.get('/incHp/:id', function (req, res) { // AJAX
  console.log("Ajax => UserId " + req.params.id);
});

app.get('/decHp/:id', function (req, res) { // AJAX
  console.log("Ajax => UserId " + req.params.id);
});

app.listen(8888, function () {
  console.log('Server running on port 8888');
});
```

and my Handlebars template contains

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Client/profile.js"></script>

<Button class="btn" onclick="increaseHitpoints()">Increase Hitpoints</Button>

<Button class="btn" onclick="decreaseHitpoints()">Decrease Hitpoints</Button>
```

When pressing the button, my client side Javascript calls these functions

```
function increaseHitpoints(){ // Increase the HP of the User 2312
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/incHp/2312'
  });
}

function decreaseHitpoints(){ // Decrease the HP of the User 2312
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/decHp/2312'
  });
}
```

but the console says the Ajax post is wrong, just show 404 error. How can I fix this?

Comment: your server is setup for process get requests. so change your method type into `get` in your client side javascript functions.

Comment: ah, okay, I will change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server side code you are using `app.get` i.e. `get` method while in your Ajax request you are using `post` method. This is conflicting there in method type.

Change your method type in function code

```
function increaseHitpoints(){ // Increase the HP of the User 2312
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', // change this
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/incHp/2312'
  });
}

function decreaseHitpoints(){ // Decrease the HP of the User 2312
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', // change this
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/decHp/2312'
  });
}
```

Comment: If it is working now then please accept my answer as correct.

Comment: I will do, just have to wait 1 more minute

Comment: Or route `/incHp/...` and `/decHp/...` as `POST` via `app.post(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, but in my case looks more strang.
After clicking the "+" button and calling the function add(). In the console log shows only six times value entered in the "input_x" field and stored in "x" variable. More don't. During these six times I can change the entered value, and then the given value doesn't show. The whole script seems to stop.
I don't know if I did it right, but I meant to pass a variable to the server side by POST method.

This is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const calculator = require('./module');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const hostname = 'localhost';

let public = path.join(__dirname, 'public')
let server_x = 0, server_y = 0;

app.use(express.static(public));

// Configuring body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.post('/api/add', function (req, res) {
  const server_x = req.body.x;
  console.log(server_x);
});

const server = app.listen(port, hostname, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log("Error in server setup")  
  const host = server.address().address;  
  const port = server.address().port;  
  console.log(`Server running at http://${host}:${port}/`);  
  });
```

This is my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Mini Calculator</title>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="page.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
    <main class="form-signin">
        <h2>JavaScript Mini Calculator</h2>
          <p>Add, subtract, multiply and divide</p>

            <div class="form-floating">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="input_x" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea">
              </div>
          </div>    

            <div class="form-floating">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="input_y" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea">
              </div>
          </div>
    
            <div class="form-floating">
                <p id="result">Result...</p>
          </div>
 
            <div class="form-floating">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-space" onclick="add()">+</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-space">-</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-space">*</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-space">/</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-space">=</button>
            </div>

    </main>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
    <script>
            let client_x = 0, client_y = 0;

        const input_x = document.getElementById("input_x");
        input_x.addEventListener('change', updateValue_x);

        const input_y = document.getElementById("input_y");
        input_y.addEventListener('change', updateValue_y);

      function updateValue_x(event){
        client_x = Number(event.target.value);
            }

        function updateValue_y(event){
            client_y = Number(event.target.value);
            }

            function add() {
                $.ajax({
                url: ' /api/add',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    x: client_x
                }
            });
            }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```